# MySQL SELECT values within range AND next values outside range in one Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT sensorNumber, rangeStartTime, rangeEndTime, sensorLow, sensorAverage, sensorHigh 
FROM rangeData 
WHERE rangeStartTime >= 0 
AND rangeEndTime <= 43200 
AND (sensorNumber = 3)
ORDER BY sensorNumber;
```

How can I make it such that I can grab just 1 previous and next values outside the rangeStartTime and rangeEndTime time span?

So in english this would be said as: **"Select all values within 5:00 pm and 7:00 pm, also select next value right before 5:00 pm and next value right after 7:00 pm."**

I tried the following by looking at other examples but it did not work:

```
SELECT sensorNumber, rangeStartTime, rangeEndTime, sensorLow, sensorAverage, sensorHigh 
FROM rangeData 
WHERE rangeStartTime >= 0 
AND rangeEndTime <= 43200 
AND rangeStartTime < 0 LIMIT 1
AND rangeEndTime > 43200 LIMIT 1
AND (sensorNumber = 3)
ORDER BY sensorNumber;
```

Each query adds 5-10 seconds of wait time so I would like to make this into one query.

Comment: post also your table definition and sample data. ( or create a fiddle )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with a simple union of 3 queries, your original one, one for the previous and one for the next:

```
(SELECT sensorNumber, rangeStartTime, rangeEndTime, sensorLow, sensorAverage, sensorHigh 
FROM rangeData 
WHERE (rangeStartTime BETWEEN 0 AND 43200) AND (sensorNumber = 3))
UNION
(SELECT sensorNumber, rangeStartTime, rangeEndTime, sensorLow, sensorAverage, sensorHigh 
FROM rangeData 
WHERE (rangeStartTime < 0) AND (sensorNumber = 3)
ORDER BY rangeStartTime DESC
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT sensorNumber, rangeStartTime, rangeEndTime, sensorLow, sensorAverage, sensorHigh 
FROM rangeData 
WHERE (rangeStartTime > 43200) AND (sensorNumber = 3)
ORDER BY rangeStartTime ASC
LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY sensorNumber;
```

(BTW: The `ORDER BY` is not needed as you're querying for only one `sensorNumber`)

Comment: This is how I would look to achieve this.

Comment: Where LIMIT is included ORDER BY is always needed

Comment: Thank you, that works. The sensorNumber values are strings so sometimes it more more than just sensor#3, thence why the ORDER BY.